# Uncaught ReferenceError: bTitle is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I got this error. but seems get "keyField" well. because it shows bTitle !

```
list.do:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: bTitle is not defined
    at PageMove (list.do:29)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

when i search specific word, it shows pages and posts well on first page.

but when i go to page 2 or next page, seaching keyword doesn't apply on and can't move to next page.

but still can't move to next page. is this address problem?

this is my code!

```
<% 
String keyWord = (String)request.getParameter("keyWord");
String keyField = (String)request.getParameter("keyField");
%>
<script>

    function searchCheck(frm){
        //검색
        if(frm.keyWord.value ==""){
            alert("검색 단어를 입력하세요.");
            frm.keyWord.focus();
            return;
        }
        frm.submit();      
    }


    function PageMove(page){
        var keyWord = <%=keyWord%>
        var keyField = <%=keyField%>
        console.log(keyWord);
        if(keyWord && keyField){
       location.href = "list.do?page="+page+"&keyWord=" + keyWord + "&keyField=" + keyField;
        }
        location.href = "list.do?page="+page;
     }

</script>

    <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>번호</td>
            <td>이름</td>
            <td>제목</td>
            <td>날짜</td>
            <td>히트</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="dto">
        <tr>
            <td>${dto.bId}</td>
            <td>${dto.bName}</td>
            <td>
                <c:forEach begin="1" end="${dto.bIndent}">-</c:forEach>
                <a href="content_view.do?bId=${dto.bId}">${dto.bTitle}</a></td>
            <td>${dto.bDate}</td>
            <td>${dto.bHit}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <form action="list.do" method="post" name="search">
                <select name="keyField">
                    <option value="bTitle">글 제목</option>
                    <option value="bContent">글 내용</option>
                    <option value="bName">작성자</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="keyWord">
                <input type="button" value="검색" onclick="searchCheck(form)">
                <%-- <input type="hidden" value="${keyWord}">
                <input type="hidden" value="${keyField}"> --%>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"> <a href="write_view.do">글작성</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%=PageAction.pageNumber() %>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
  <div class="toolbar mt-lg">
    <div class="sorter">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.firstPageNo})">맨앞으로</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.prevPageNo})">앞으로</a></li>
              <c:forEach var="i" begin="${paging.startPageNo}" end="${paging.endPageNo}" step="1">
                  <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${i eq paging.pageNo}">
                <li class="active"><a href="javascript:PageMove(${i})">${i}</a></li>
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>
                        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${i})">${i}</a></li>
                      </c:otherwise>
                  </c:choose>
              </c:forEach>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.nextPageNo})">뒤로</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.finalPageNo})">맨뒤로</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

BListCommand.java

```
public class BListCommand implements BCommand {


    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        BDao dao = new BDao();
        String keyField = request.getParameter("keyField");
        String keyWord = request.getParameter("keyWord");
        System.out.println("키워드는~~:??"+keyField);
        List<BDto> dtos  ;
        int totalCount = dao.getTotalRecord(keyField,keyWord);
        System.out.println(totalCount);
        int page = request.getParameter("page") == null ? 1 : Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));

        Paging paging = new Paging();
        paging.setPageNo(page); //get방식의 parameter값으로 반은 page변수, 현재 페이지 번호
        paging.setPageSize(10); // 한페이지에 불러낼 게시물의 개수 지정
        paging.setTotalCount(totalCount);

        paging.setKeyField(keyField);
        paging.setKeyWord(keyWord);
        System.out.println("페이지넘버BListCommand"+page);
        page = (page - 1) * 10; //select해오는 기준을 구한다.
        System.out.println("페이지넘버BListCommand"+page);

        int endpage=page+10;
        dtos = dao.getBoardList(page+1, endpage,keyField,keyWord);


        request.setAttribute("paging", paging);
        request.setAttribute("list", dtos);
        request.setAttribute("keyField", paging.getkeyField());
        request.setAttribute("keyWord", paging.getKeyWord());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain you intended your variable values to be strings. You need to write:

```
var keyWord = '<%=keyWord%>'
var keyField = '<%=keyField%>'
```

Notice the single quotes round the output from Java. This will make JavaScript treat the output values as strings. Right now, the way you're outputting them means that it sees them as variable names, but of course those variables do not exist in your JavaScript.

Comment: thanks! it works. do you have any idea of why searching keyword doesn't apply on  ? still when i search specific word only first page is classified. next page shows original next page :(

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure what you mean. You might be better to ask a new question about it then you can give more detail and a proper example.